# "number one way" hyphen

Tags: hyphens

> The number (-) one way to make someone less stressed is to appreciate them and their struggle, support them no matter what, and share your experience of dealing with a similar problem.

Should there be a hyphen in "number-one way"? CMOS says number + noun (a hundred-meter race, a 250-page book, a fifty-year project) are hyphenated before a noun, otherwise open. But here I have noun + number. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there shouldn't be a hyphen. It is an error.

'Number one', used this way, is an *adjective*. Compound adjectives often *do* have hyphens (eg 'blue-green', or 'six-foot'). However, as you point out, both 'number' and 'one' are nouns ('one' *can* be an adjective, too, but as a name for the ordinal, it is a noun) and compound nouns do not always have hyphens. So, in actual fact, it is a compound noun being used as an adjective.

You'll see from a [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/number%20one) that 'number one' used as an adjective to mean the first in rank is not written with a hyphen.

Comment: Thanks, @Astralbee! I haven't thought of checking out M-W on that!

Comment: More than a few of Lexico's example sentences for "number one" (as an adjective) are hyphenated ( https://www.lexico.com/definition/number_one ), although many are not, so it may be an error.